# Como calcular a diferença entre a hora do servidor e o computador do usuário?

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso adaptar meu código para calcular a diferença entre o horário do servidor onde o site está hospedado e do horário do computador do usuário para não sobrecarregar meu sistema.

Estou montando uma tabela onde mostrarei o horário de um outro servidor e precisa atualizar a cada um segundo.

Então eu tenho que obter três dados:

1. Horário do servidor onde o site está hospedado
2. Horário do dispositivo que está acessando o site para saber a diferença entre o horário do servidor
3. Diferença do terceiro servidor que será recalculado a cada segundo

O terceiro item eu tenho definido em JavaScript da seguinte maneira:

```
<script>
var difJogo = (-145);
</script>
```

Significa que o servidor do jogo está 145 segundos atrasados em relação ao servidor do site (referência principal).

Para obter o horário do servidor do site eu utilizo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$cH = date('G');
$cM = date('i');
$cS = date('s');
echo $cH .':'. $cM .':'. $cS;
?>
```

E para obter o horário do dispositivo do usuário uso:

```
<script>
function hat() {
    var sAg = ( Date.now() / 1000 ) % 86400;
}
</script>
```

O que eu não consigo é unir todas essas funções para chegar aonde quero. O horário do servidor do site precisa ser a base de tudo pois tem gente que acessa o site de diversos lugares do mundo, então quero definir que o horário seja igual para todos usando fuso horário de São Paulo.

A lógica final é: `Horário do servidor - Horário do dispositivo + Diferença do Jogo.`

Com isso, é necessário uma função para exibir o horário do servidor do jogo e atualizar a cada 1 segundo.

Comment: parece q vc tá usando php serverside e js clientside. voce quer o dado no cliente ou no servidor? de qualquer forma eu faria um endpoint no servidor que recebe a data do cliente, ou que devolvesse a data do servidor pro cliente, dependendo de onde voce quer usar o valor final

Answer (score 2):

Você está envolvendo variáveis PHP (server-side) com variáveis Javascript (client-side). É preciso definir uma estratégia - ou você passa a variável [Javascript pro PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php) ou a [variável PHP pro Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript).

Eu preferiria o último método, pois faz mais sentido enviar informações do servidor para o cliente, e me parece que o contrário (Javascript para PHP) é feito através de métodos não-convencionais (i.e., a maioria dos métodos parecem gambiarras).

Mas por se tratar de um jogo, é importante pensar que se você deixar informações que sejam relevantes para a lógica do mesmo (como parece ser o caso do horário) no código do lado do cliente, eventualmente um engraçadinho com algum conhecimento de Javascript vai alterar variáveis para "trapacear" no jogo.

Portanto, tente enviar o horário do cliente do Javascript para o PHP dessa forma:

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var PageToSendTo = "script_jogo.php?";
var MyVariable = "sAg";
var VariablePlaceholder = "horaDoCliente=";
var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + MyVariable;

xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, false);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Dessa forma, o horário do cliente será enviado para o servidor de forma assíncrona (sem atualizar a página no browser). Depois disso, seu `script_jogo.php` deverá fazer os demais cálculos de diferença de horário, etc. Claro, ainda assim alguém poderia tentar enviar um horário diferente - ou até mesmo alterar a hora do sistema no computador como "cheat"; esse tipo de caso também precisa ser bem cuidado e previsto pelo `script_jogo.php` para captar algo que saia do normal.

Minha sugestão: no cadastro do jogo, o usuário deverá informar seu local, e o fuso-horário deverá então ser salvo no banco de dados. Dessa forma, você evitaria todo esse fluxo de envio de variável de hora e gerenciaria tudo via PHP no lado do servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Pode não ser a melhor solução, mas a maneira mais simples que encontrei para usar o PHP dentro do JavaScript como era o objetivo de sua pergunta, seria dessa forma:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $Sh = date('G');
    $sM = date('i');
    $sS = date('s');
    $rS = ($Sh*60*60)+($sM*60)+$sS;
?>

<script>
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ funRelogio() }, 1);
    var tServ = <?php echo $rS; ?>;
    var hr = new Date();
    var secn = hr.getSeconds() + (60 * (hr.getMinutes() + (60 * hr.getHours())));

function funRelogio() {
    var difArcadia = (100);
    var dt = new Date();
    var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * (dt.getMinutes() + (60 * dt.getHours())));
    var difT = tServ - secn;
    var hrArc = secs + difArcadia - difT;
    var hHarc = Math.floor(hrArc/3600%24);
    var hMarc = Math.floor(hrArc/60%60);
    var hSarc = Math.floor(hrArc%60);
    var result =  hHarc + ":" + hMarc + ":" + hSarc;
document.getElementById("hArc").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<p id="hArc"></p>
```

Ao que me parece, o código acima funcionou para criar um relógio que verifique a hora atual do servidor quando a página é carregada, utilizando o PHP, em seguida, utilizando do JavScript, podemos capturar a hora atual do usuário e ainda usar operações básicas para calcular a diferença do servidor de hospedagem, do dispositivo do usuário e acrescentar a diferença do servidor do jogo conforme solicitado.

Para criar a resposta, utilizei como base [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415885/5429657) sobre PHP dentro do JavaScript, e [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700358/5429657) para formatar os segundos no padrão h:m:s.

Sou leigo no assunto, por isso, fiquem a vontade para editar ou usar de base minha resposta, em uma solução mais adequada.

Comment: exatamente isso, fazendo uma chamada do servidor apenas uma vez e convertendo o resultado para javascript, assim não vai sobrecarregar o servidor do site (hospedagem compartilhada), pois o que vai ficar rodando é o javascript

Answer (score 1):

É possível simplificar o problema trabalhando com horas em UTC. assim poderá trabalhar as datas via timezone tanto no PHP quanto no javascript.

## PHP

No PHP utilize a função [`gmdate`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) ela sempre irá retornar a data e hora de Greenwich, e então poderá aplicar a timezone que for necessária.

Para fazer conversões de timezone basta fazer:

```
// Cria um objeto com a data atual UTC
$dt = new DateTime(gmdate('Y/m/d H:i:s'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

// Altera a timezone
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));

// format the datetime
$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
```

## Javascript

No javascript para converter a data de UTC para local faça

```
var date = new Date('6/29/2011 4:52:48 PM UTC');
date.toString() // 1º forma
date.toLocaleString() // 2º forma
```

[Veja aqui uma documentação sobre as funções de data em javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

[Uma resposta sobre conversões de data UTC para o formato local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)