# setInterval não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, javascript, html

Gostaria de executar uma função infinitamente a cada um segundo, estou tentando desta forma mas a função só é executada uma vez:

*Entre a tag body*

```
    <div id="map"><div id="seg"></div></div>
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $Sh = date('G');
    $sM = date('i');
    $sS = date('s');
    $rS = ($Sh*60*60)+($sM*60)+$sS;
    ?>
```

*Entre a tag script*

```
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ mudarHora() }, 1000);
    var tServ = <?php echo $rS; ?> + 3;
    function mudarHora() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * (dt.getMinutes() + (60 * dt.getHours())));
    var difT = tServ - secs;
    var segundosAgora = secs + difT;
    document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = segundosAgora;
    }
```

Como falei a função é executada apenas uma vez e não sei onde está o erro.

Comment: A função está correta. O erro está no cálculo. A variável `segundosAgora` **sempre** terá o mesmo valor.

Comment: @valdeirpsr quando atualizo a página manualmente o valor de segundosAgora muda, por que diz que sempre terá o mesmo valor?

Comment: Se você adicionar um `console.log( segundosAgora );` dentro da função `mudarHora`, verás (F12) que o valor sempre será o mesmo, apesar da função está funcionando. Demonstração: https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/rJpvdr

Comment: @valdeirpsr no codepen não é possível trabalhar com php (acho) e você definiu const tServ = 65438; onde 65438 na verdade é um número dinâmico (segundo atual do dia - lado do servidor). Como o valor de tServ está fixo no seu exemplo, é por isso que o segundosAgora é sempre o mesmo, não?

Comment: @talnum ele está falando do seu cálculo de `segundosAgora`, que não faz sentido. `tServ - secs + secs = tServ`, sempre.

Comment: @talnun Esse valor é fixo. O *PHP* não trabalha com valores dinâmicos no lado do cliente (Exceto quando atualiza a página). Enquanto você mantiver a página aberta, **o valor não muda**. Para o valor da variável `tServ` ser alterado (sem refresh), você deve fazer isso com *JavaScript*.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr a intenção era esta, acho: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZVqPx?editors=1111

Comment: Era mais fácil dizer qual é o resultado desejado. O setInterval está funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Editado*

Então a dificuldade é para reiniciar a função pelo TIMER em javascript?
Se for tente usar `setTimeout`:

```
var tServ = <?php echo $rS; ?> + 3;
function mudarHora() {
   var dt = new Date();
   var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * (dt.getMinutes() + (60 * dt.getHours())));
   var difT = tServ - secs;
   var segundosAgora = secs + difT;
   document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = segundosAgora;
   setTimeout(function(){ mudarHora() }, 1000);
}
```

Para disparar a função use o evento `onload` assim:

```
<body onload="mudarHora()">
```

Ficará assim o código completo:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$Sh = date('G');
$sM = date('i');
$sS = date('s');
$rS = ($Sh*60*60)+($sM*60)+$sS;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var tServ = <?php echo $rS; ?> + 3;
function mudarHora() {
   var dt = new Date();
   var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * (dt.getMinutes() + (60 * dt.getHours())));
   var difT = tServ - secs;
   var segundosAgora = secs + difT;
   document.getElementById("seg").innerHTML = segundosAgora;
   setTimeout(function(){ mudarHora() }, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="mudarHora()">
<div id="map"><div id="seg"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: na verdade não, obter o horário do servidor eu já consegui nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/256698/90997. A sugestão que você me ofereceu tem grandes chances de sobrecarregar meu servidor compartilhado como já aconteceu, pois faz muitas requisições ao arquivo realtime.php dependendo do número de acessos ao mesmo tempo, mas obrigada.

Comment: Modificado, veja se o problema era este, eu testei e funcionou.

Comment: @talnun e RpgBoss Provavelmente o erro não é no setInterval vs setTimeout e sim algum erro de script ou de outro script, provavelmente olhando para o console irá notar falhas emitidas e irá saber a origem do problema. Provavelmente o DOM não esta carregado no momento que o script inicia, então o onload pode resolver como o RpgBoss sugeriu, ainda sim creio que algo mais rápido e eficiente que onload seja usar `DOMContentLoaded`, ou melhor ainda algo como isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/137881/3635

Comment: Agora que percebi que ela chamou o PHP depois de tudo pelo que entendi.
Vou postar o exemplo completo...

Comment: funcionou certinho